# Pinterest's first tab is UITableView or UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiwebview, pinterest

I wonder which view is used in the next image?

UITableView or UIWebView?

I always wondered how one can tell if a view is embedded inside a web view or not.
Anyway, anyone knows the answer for this specific view?

[image]

Comment: please elaborate your question technically..not poetically

Comment: Each `UITableViewCell` can have different height so that's not a correct argument to say if it's `UITableView` or anything else.

Comment: This question should be targeted at Pinterest as only they know for sure, everyone else here can only elaborate. (seems native to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set individual height to individual UITableViewCell using this delegate Method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: And you can also build a robot and gather earth samples from Mars, but that's only as related to the OP's question as your answer.

Comment: actually I reasoned, it'd not be a tableview because I can't vary the height of cell. but he's opposing it.

Comment: @H2CO3 And you will be the guide for that robot to gather the earth samples in Mars??? The question is its table view or web view and how can we set different height to each cell. You didnt get that point

Comment: @Sumanth frankly, I don't even see the table cell's height mentioned in the question. "I wonder which view is used in the next image?

UITableView or UIWebView?

I always wondered how one can tell if a view is embedded inside a web view or not.
Anyway, anyone knows the answer for this specific view?" Where's the point about the height?